# How to where clause of two value in the same field?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have 3 tables

**objects**

```
ID || NAME
====================
1  || object title 
--------------------
2  || name of object
etc..
```

**props**

```
ID || NAME
===========
1  || draft
-----------
2  || views
etc..
```

**obj_props**

```
ID || OID || PID || VALUE
=========================
1  || 1   || 1   || 1
-------------------------
1  || 1   || 2   || 70
etc..
```

I need to select records where *draft* = 1 and *views* > 0.

My current mysql query:

```
SELECT o.id, p.name as prop_name, op.value as prop_val 
FROM objects o 
INNER JOIN obj_props op ON o.id = op.object_id 
INNER JOIN props p ON p.id = op.prop_id 
WHERE p.name = 'views' and op.value > 0
```

but when I added

```
AND p.name = 'draft' and op.value = 1
```

it returns null.

If replace AND operator with OR - code returns all records but I need search props of single object.

Answer (score 6):

You need to use `OR` **with brackets**:

```
WHERE (p.name = 'views' AND op.value > 0)
   OR (p.name = 'draft' AND op.value = 1)
```